# How to add outlets to a viewController that is not the file owner of a xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am refactoring a viewController, but have to leave the old viewController in place to A/B test between the two.

Both of these viewControllers can use the same xib and have the same outlets. However, the xib can only have 1 viewController as its file owner.

Xcode does not allow me to drag outlets into the other viewController since it is not an owner of the xib.

I have heard that technically connecting outlets to a non-owner file is allowed by ios as long as the outlook signatures are correct.

Is there a way to do this through xcode?

Comment: File's owner is the actual instance of the class that loaded the XIB. If both classes load the XIB and both have the same outlets, you may find that they are already hooked up properly. Have you tried it?

Comment: Oh, even if I don't drag a link from the xib to the file? I already all the outlets defined. I'll try it now